# How to create a truly responsive design in flutter using stack and positioned widget

Tags: flutter, dart, responsive

I thought of using `Stack` and `Positioned` widget thinking it will be a responsive design by default, i even tried the `Sizer` plugin but for some reason I unable to create a truly responsive design and my widgets are all over the place on different screen

please take a look at my code

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    return Stack(
      children: [
        Googlelutter(mapKey: _mapKey, osmController: osmController),
        Positioned(
          top: 60.0,
          left: 0.0,
          right: 0.0,
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
                child: Consumer<AppData>(
                  builder: (ctx, dsc, child) => (ElevatedButton(
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                        shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius:
                                BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(50))),
                        backgroundColor: dsc.driverStatusClr),
                    // color: dsc.driverStatusClr,
                    onPressed: () async {
                      if (isDriverAvailable != true) {
                        isDriverAvailable = true;
                        makeDriverOnlineNow();
                        getLocationLiveUpdates();

                        Provider.of<AppData>(context, listen: false)
                            .buttonOnline(Colors.green.shade300, "Online");

                        await UserSimplePrefences.setButtonStatus(false);

                        // });
                        displayToastMessage("You are Online now", context);
                      } else {
                        Provider.of<AppData>(context, listen: false)
                            .buttonOnline(Colors.black54, "Offline");
                        driverOffline();
                        IsolateNameServer.removePortNameMapping(_isolateName);
                        BackgroundLocator.unRegisterLocationUpdate();
                        displayToastMessage("You are Offline now", context);
                        isDriverAvailable = false;

                        await UserSimplePrefences.setButtonStatus(true);

                        onStop();
                      }
                    },
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(17),
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            dsc.driverStatusTxt,
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 20.0,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                color: Colors.white),
                          ),
                          Icon(
                            Icons.phone_android,
                            color: Colors.white,
                            size: 26,
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  )),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Positioned(
          top: 700.0,
          right: 22.0,
          child: GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              osmController.currentLocation();
            },
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(22.0),
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      blurRadius: 6.0,
                      spreadRadius: 0.5,
                      offset: Offset(
                        0.7,
                        0.7,
                      ),
                    )
                  ]),
              child: CircleAvatar(
                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.location_on,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
                radius: 20.0,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Positioned(
          top: 100.0,
          right: 22.0,
          child: GestureDetector(
            onTap: () async {
              //FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
              await osmController.enableTracking();
            },
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(22.0),
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      blurRadius: 6.0,
                      spreadRadius: 0.5,
                      offset: Offset(
                        0.7,
                        0.7,
                      ),
                    )
                  ]),
              child: CircleAvatar(
                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.track_changes,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
                radius: 20.0,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

and let me know how can I fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this... with respect to device height width.

```
double deviceHeight:MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
double deviceWidth=MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

double width=350;
double height=500;
void checkDevice(){
if(deviceWidth<600) return;
if(deviceWidth>600 && 
deviceWidth<1024){
//for tablet size
width=800;
height=800;
}else{
//for web pages size in desktop
 width=1500;
 height=1500;
}

}



@override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
super.build(context);
return SizedBox(width:deviceWidth,height:deviceHeight:child:Fittedbox(child: SizedBox(width:width,height:height,childStack(
  children: [
    Googlelutter(mapKey: _mapKey, osmController: osmController),
    Positioned(
      top: height*0.7,
      left: 0.0,
      right: 0.0,
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: width*0.1),
            child: Consumer<AppData>(
              builder: (ctx, dsc, child) => (ElevatedButton(
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                    shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius:
                            BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(width*0.7))),
                    backgroundColor: dsc.driverStatusClr),
                // color: dsc.driverStatusClr,
                onPressed: () async {
                  if (isDriverAvailable != true) {
                    isDriverAvailable = true;
                    makeDriverOnlineNow();
                    getLocationLiveUpdates();

                    Provider.of<AppData>(context, listen: false)
                        .buttonOnline(Colors.green.shade300, "Online");

                    await UserSimplePrefences.setButtonStatus(false);

                    // });
                    displayToastMessage("You are Online now", context);
                  } else {
                    Provider.of<AppData>(context, listen: false)
                        .buttonOnline(Colors.black54, "Offline");
                    driverOffline();
                    IsolateNameServer.removePortNameMapping(_isolateName);
                    BackgroundLocator.unRegisterLocationUpdate();
                    displayToastMessage("You are Offline now", context);
                    isDriverAvailable = false;

                    await UserSimplePrefences.setButtonStatus(true);

                    onStop();
                  }
                },
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(width*0.01),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        dsc.driverStatusTxt,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 12,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                      Icon(
                        Icons.phone_android,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        size: width*0.05,
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              )),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
    Positioned(
      top: height*0.7,
      right: width*0.2,
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          osmController.currentLocation();
        },
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              borderRadius: width*0.07,BorderRadius.circular(width*0.05),
              boxShadow: [
                BoxShadow(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  blurRadius:width*0.005,
                  spreadRadius: width*0.007,
                  offset: Offset(
                    width*0.007,
                    width*0.007,
                  ),
                )
              ]),
          child: CircleAvatar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            child: Icon(
              Icons.location_on,
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
            radius: width*0.07,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
    Positioned(
      top: height*0.07,
      right: width*0.07,
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () async {
          //FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
          await osmController.enableTracking();
        },
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(width*0.07),
              boxShadow: [
                BoxShadow(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  blurRadius: width*0.007,
                  spreadRadius: width*0.005,
                  offset: Offset(
                    width*0.005,
                    width*0.005,
                  ),
                )
              ]),
          child: CircleAvatar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            child: Icon(
              Icons.track_changes,
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
            radius: width*0.01,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],))),
);
```

}

Comment: Nooo. `fontSize: width*0.01,` Never Never Never change the fontsize based on the width of your screen!!!  When you pull your web page wider, does the text get bigger?  No, it stays the same size and re-flows.